# problem with htaccess RewriteRule with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an .htaccess file in the folder www/intranet/ :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /intranet/
RewriteRule ^administration/profils/editer/(\d+)/?$ administration-profils-editer.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article/(\d+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The url administration/profils/editer/1/ is working fine, but url article/1/ does not works. It display the page article.php, but parameter id is not working.

Beside of that, when I hit article.php?id=1, it does work.

Also, if I do something like this in htaccess `RewriteRule ^test/article/(\d+)/?$ article.php?id=$1 [L]` it works, I am getting the id parameter.

I can't get it works fine :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be problem due to [Apache's content negotiation module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/content-negotiation.html). This module runs **before** `mod_rewrite` module and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So if `/article` is the URI then Apache will automatically rewrites to `/article.php` (if that file is found in the path). Due to this when your rewrite rule runs it doesn't match regex patten `^article/(\d+)/?$`.

You will need to turn off content negotiation feature by turning off `MultiViews` option.

So in short add this line on top of your .htaccess:

```bash
Options -MultiViews
```

Comment: Aaaah this works fine !!! Sorry for the delay.